# Bluetooth Upload is Hanging

Tags: bluetooth, hc-05

I am trying to program my Arduino via bluetooth and have been following this tutorial very closely in order to do so: https://www.instructables.com/Program-an-Arduino-Wireless-Over-Bluetooth/

I have been able to put my HC-05 into AT command mode, entered the commands, and received the "OK" responses. When I go to try to upload the code, however, the sketch usually hangs and nothing happens. The TX on my HC-05 goes to the Arduino RX, RX to TX, VCC to 5V, GND to GND, and EN to RESET.

I am able to see the device no problem on my windows computer and seem to be using the correct port. Any ideas on how to fix the issue?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is EN pin?

Comment: I think it is the same as the Pin 32 or something. My HC-05 only has STATE, VCC, GND, TXD, RXD, and EN.

Comment: as you can see in the tutorial the wire for reset is solder directly to the Bluetooth module. it is not a random pin.

Comment: How should I connect the HC-05 to the Bluetooth module then?

Comment: do you have the reset wire soldered to the BT module?

Comment: I was just reading this tutorial: https://www.fpaynter.com/2019/06/arduino-remote-programming-using-a-hc-05-bluetooth-module/ which indicated that I instead should connect the STATE pin to the Arduino's RESET pin. It still is not working though.

Comment: I was just reading more of that tutorial again - my HC-05 shows no lights or anything when plugged in. Is that a problem?